# Svelte: How to implement use:tippy on a nested component

Tags: javascript, svelte

I've found the [`svelte-tippy`](https://github.com/mdauner/sveltejs-tippy) implementation of the tooltip library [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) which I understand is a Svelte Action, i.e. it uses the `use:tippy` attribute, like this:

```
<button use:tippy={props}>
  Hover me
</button>
```

How would I go about implementing a Tippy.js tooltip for a [heatmap](https://github.com/scottbedard/svelte-heatmap)?  The configuration (at least, `true`/`false` for using tooltips, but also some template or function for the actual tooltip contents) would happen at the top-level component (`SvelteHeatmap`), but the actual implementation would happen on the `Cell` level which represents a day, with the `Month` or `Week` components, respectively, in between, and would be based on the configuration provided on the top-level.

As I would like to suggest a Pull Request for the [Svelte Heatmap](https://github.com/scottbedard/svelte-heatmap) component but am only a Svelte beginner, I'd like to get some generic explanation as to how this works, or should work. The official documentation has some info on Actions, but not really a best practice for this kind of thing (I may be wrong about this though).

Note I've made a basic test to make sure this [works with SVG](https://codesandbox.io/s/sveltejs-tippy-forked-u7tgo?file=/App.svelte), it does.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything really that would clearly explain how to do this. After some fiddling I came up with this use

```html
<div id="my_selector"></div>

<div id="nested_elements"> 
    <button>Option_1</button>
    <button>Option_2</button>
    <button>Option_3</button>
</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
```

```js
tippy('#my_selector', {
            content: document.querySelector('#nested_elements').innerHTML,
            interactive: true,
            allowHTML: true,
          });
```